# Enabling and disabling of columns in Infragistics UltraGrid

Tags: c#, infragistics

I have an Infragistics grid and I want to disable and enable some columns based upon some requirement. I have read some articles that say to use `AllowUpdate = DefaultableBoolean.True` but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 14):

I suppose that when you talk of disabled columns you mean disable editing in these columns.
Also you don't specify the language, so I will use C#

```
UltraGridColumn c = grdWork.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["YourColumnName"];
c.CellActivation = Activation.NoEdit; 
c.CellClickAction = CellClickAction.CellSelect;
```

The property **CellActivation** could also be set to `Activation.Disabled` or `Activation.ActivateOnly`.
The property **CellClickAction** allows to set an appropriate selection status for the cell clicked. You could use `CellSelect` or `RowSelect`. (This last one, to mimic the behavior of a ListBox)
As usual, the real difficulty is to find the correct property. Then Intellisense will give you a quick and fair explanation of the meaning of these values.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to show and hide the columns as needed then you can try the following.

```
UltraGrid myGrid = new UltraGrid();
//Bind to your data here
myGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["ColumnName"].Hidden = true;
```