# How to set disable cell on cell level instead of whole column

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, infragistics, ultrawingrid

According to the solution on column level:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11803015/1460189

```
private void dg_CellListSelect(object sender, CellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cell.Column.Key == "someID")
            e.Cell.Row.Cells["someColumn"].Activation = Activation.NoEdit;
        //Property or indexer cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
    }
```

Based on certain logic on particular cell, i want to disable it but apparently couldnt set the value for attribute `Activation`?

Comment: Which version of Infragistics do you use?

Comment: What you mean by "I cannot set the value for Activation"? Do you get some error? Or you get some exception?

Answer (score 0):

If by disabled you mean user isn't allowed to edit the cell, then I think you want the ReadOnly property.

```
e.Cell.Row.Cells["someColumn"].ReadOnly = false;
```

Comment: There is no `ReadOnly` tag available